# Phaser animation stops while switching tab

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I am developing a card game using **Phaser**. When I switch the tab, the card animation stops. I **don't want the animation to stop**.

I have applied the below code to prevent this:

```
game.stage.disableVisibilityChange = true;
```

But I am unable to make phaser animation running while switching tab.

Comment: Nothing Phaser can do about that unfortunately. http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/10847-gamestagedisablevisibilitychange-not-working/?do=findComment&comment=68185

Comment: Isn't there any other way to achieve this?